# ¿Cuál es el flujo interno de una función de iteradores en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteradores

Estoy viendo el tema de los Iteradores y cómo crearlos, pero no logro entender el flujo paso a paso de esta función.

```
class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Cuando ejecuto este código:

```
a = PowTwo(4)
i = list(iter(a))
print(i)
```

Obtengo esta salida:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Comment: quiza esto te ayude: https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/11/iteradores-y-generadores.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un iterador conceptualmente es lo que te ha explicado Patricio.

En esta respuesta me voy a centrar más en cómo lo implementa python, y cómo funciona tu código.

Desde el punto de vista de la implementación, un iterador es un objeto que implementa el método `__next__()`. Si el objeto `a` tiene ese método, Python podrá hacer `next(a)` y cada vez que lo haga, obtendrá un nuevo valor de una serie. Esa serie no tiene por qué estar almacenada en ningún sitio, puede ser generada sobre la marcha, como es de hecho el caso en tu ejemplo. La serie podría ser infinita, es decir, devolver siempre un nuevo valor cada vez que se llame a `next(a)`. O podría ser finita si en algún momento `next(a)` genera la excepción `StopIteration`

Un iterador es creado por python automáticamente cuando haces un bucle `for`, ya que Python, cuando ve algo como `for elemento in algo`, intentará convertir `algo` en un iterador llamando a `iter(algo)`. Si esa función tiene éxito retornará un objeto, digamos `iterador`, sobre el que ya se podrá hacer `next(iterador)` para ir obteniendo valores.

Es decir, en esencia, el bucle `for` que escribimos de forma tan simple como:

```
for elemento in algo:
   print(elemento)
print("Terminó el bucle")
```

es en realidad ejecutado por Python así:

```
iterador = iter(algo)
while True:
    try:
       elemento = next(iterador)
       print(elemento)
    except StopIteration:
       break  # Esta excepción se ignora, pero sirve para salir del bucle
print("Terminó el bucle")
```

Así pues, para que el  `for` funcione, es necesario primero que `iter(algo)` funcione. Para ello `algo` debe implementar el método `__iter__()`, que devuelva un objeto que como hemos visto hemos asignado a la variable auxiliar `iterador` (**Nota** un objeto que implementa `__iter__()` permite por tanto que se pueda iterar sobre él, y es lo que se llama un **iterable**)

También es necesario que eso que ha devuelto `algo.__iter__()` implemente `.__next__()`, pues es lo que se usará para ir sacando elementos. (**Nota** un objeto que implementa `.__next__()` se llama un **iterador**).

Y finalmente es necesario que `iterador.__next__()` en algún momento eleve la excepción `StopIteration` para que el bucle se de por terminado.

Vayamos entonces con tu clase:

```
class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Vemos que esta clase implementa `__iter__()`, por lo tanto es un **iterable**, un objeto que podríamos usar en un `for` así:

```
a = PowTwo(4)
for elemento in a:
    print(a)
```

Como vimos, lo primero que Python hará será tratar de convertir `a` en un iterador, llamando a `iter(a)`, que se convierte en una llamada a `a.__iter__()`. Pero ya que el objeto `a` *ya es un iterador* porque también implementa `__next__()`, se limita a retornarse a sí mismo. De ahí el `return self`.

> Es decir, tu objeto es a la vez un **iterable** (porque implementa `__iter__()`) y un **iterador** (porque implementa `__next__()`). Esta práctica es común, y fuente de confusión entre ambos términos que ya de por sí son bastante parecidos y liosos...

Después, para cada iteración del bucle Python hará `next(iterador)`, que en este caso acaba siendo `a.__next__()`, por lo que esta función retornará el siguiente valor de la secuencia, o bien cuando decida que ya no hay más valores, elevará `StopIteration`.

Para terminar de explicar tu código, basta decir que `list(a)` en el fondo es convertido por python en un bucle `for` así:

```
[elemento for elemento in a]
```

lo que internamente causa las mismas acciones sobre el objeto `a` que si hubieras hecho:

```
lista = []
for elemento in a:
   lista.append(elemento)
```

es decir, también llamará a `iter(a)` (por lo que no necesitas hacerlo tú), y después a `next()` sobre el iterador obtenido, una y otra vez, hasta que el iterador eleve `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 0):

Un *iterador* de manera muy general, es un objeto que implementa una colección de elementos, pero con una particularidad notable, cada elemento de dicha colección se recupera bajo demanda. También lo podríamos entender como un "constructor" dinámico de una colección de objetos/elementos.

Imagina un archivo o base de datos enorme, y que necesitas recorrer fila a fila, ¿es necesario leer completamente dicho archivo en memoria, para luego procesar cada elemento de manera individual? ¿Acaso no me voy a quedar sin recursos con semejante cantidad de información en memoria? ¿Y si solo debo leer algunas pocas filas hasta determinada condición y luego finalizar el proceso? Si te haces alguna de estas preguntas, sin duda tienes chances de necesitar un *iterador*.

La forma más básica de *iterar*  un *iterador* podría ser:

```
for elemento in mi_iterador:
  print(elemento)
```

Sin embargo, también hay casos dónde implícitamente estas iterando sobre la colección completa, esto es lo que ocurre cuando transformas un *iterador*  en un lista, por ejemplo:

```
mi_lista = list(mi_iterador)
```

En este caso, se recorre completamente todos los elementos de `mi_iterador`, sea 1, 100, o 1.000.000, por la sencilla razón que estamos promoviendo el *iterador*  a una lista. Hay que tener siempre cuidado en estos casos,  ¿es realmente lo queremos hacer?, pensemos incluso, que un *iterador* podría implementar un lista circular que no tenga fin.

En tu código, la resolución de la demanda de cada un nuevo elemento se implementa mediante el método `__next__(self)`. Una aclaración previa con `list(iter(a))`, no hace falta hacer `iter(a)` por que `a` ya es un *iterador*. Puedes entender gráficamente el flujo si implementas un mensaje en cada evento:

```
class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        print("__init__()")
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        print("__iter__()")
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print("__next__()")
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            print("StopIteration")
            raise StopIteration


a = PowTwo(4)
i = list(a)
print(i)
```

La Salida:

```
__init__()
__iter__()
__next__()
__next__()
__next__()
__next__()
__next__()
__next__()
StopIteration
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

El objeto `PowTwo(4)` inicializa un *iterador* que nos va a entregar hasta 5 elementos, ya que 4 es el máximo inclusivo de `self.n` el cual comienza de 0, de ahí los 5.

Cuando hacemos `list(a)`, por lo antes mencionado, estamos ejecutando la iteración completa, vemos, efectivamente que se ejecuta `__next__()`unas 6 veces, que corresponden a los 5 elementos generados y a la iteración final que termina de construir la colección enviando un `StopIteration`.